# Adventure Mode legendaries on first boss kill

Tags: diablo-iii

Does the improved boss loot on first kill occur in adventure mode? If so, does it count toward the first kill loot in campaign mode?

Since it seems to be tied to resetting the campaign I am not sure that it should or would work that way but I have not seen anything that documents how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the guaranteed legendary drop is for story mode only.